# CodeIgniter force csv file download

Tags: codeigniter

I have a button that runs the below code. The csv file writes fine, but for some reason it is not downloading. Nothing happens, no errors. I have used the force download before and it has worked fine.

Any ideas?

```
    $csvContent = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);

    $date = date('U');
    $filename = date('Y-m-d-Gis', $date); 

    if (!write_file("./reports/$filename.csv", $csvContent)) {
        echo 'Unable to write the file';
    } else {
        echo 'File written!';

        $data = file_get_contents("reports/$filename.csv");
        force_download($filename, $data); 

    }
```

Comment: Using `date('Y-m-d-Gis', date('U')); ` is the same as just `date('Y-m-d-Gis')` a little less complicated...

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to write the file? You could just output the CSV. With the proper headers sent, a download is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `$data = file_get_contents("./reports/$filename.csv");` instead ;)